# Comparing items in one list with corresponding items in a second list

Tags: excel, list, vba, validation

I've been asked in work to put together a quick way to validate a list of data in Excel, but it's a bit too complicated to do via nested IFs so I'm trying to do it via a macro.

Bit of a background about the data:

We run courses, and for each course there is a corresponding add-on they have to take as well. People have to chose 2 courses, and so that means 2 corresponding add-ons.

In each row in Excel, the 2 courses are in columns F and G, and the corresponding add-ons are in columns H and I.

The slight problem is that the data in columns H and I isn't necessarily in the 'correct' order - the add-on for the course in column F might be in column I on one row, and in column H in another (and the same the the add-on for column G)

There is a table in a second sheet which lists which add-ons are correct for which courses (column A has the courses and column B has the matching add-on).

What's the best/easiest way to highlight which rows are correct and which ones are not?

I can upload a small anonymised sample of the file to Dropbox if needed, but a quick layout of the data is as below:

```
| 1st Course Choice | 2nd Course Choice | 1st Add-on | 2nd Add-on | Result
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     Subject 1     |     Subject 2     |  Add-on 1  |  Add-on 2  | Correct
|     Subject 2     |     Subject 1     |  Add-on 1  |  Add-on 2  | Correct
|     Subject 3     |     Subject 9     |  Add-on 9  |  Add-on 3  | Correct
|     Subject 5     |     Subject 4     |  Add-on 1  |  Add-on 2  | Error
|     Subject 8     |     Subject 2     |  Add-on 7  |  Add-on 8  | Error
```

Comment: On what basis or how you judge which entry is correct and which is not? Your example table is not quite clear.

Comment: @PareshJ Sorry, forgot to add that bit in. I've updated the question to show that there is a second sheet in the file which lists the correct add-ons for each course

Comment: It looks like the add-on suffix numbers need to always match the course suffix numbers, although not necessarily in the same order, as you said. Is that correct? If so, it seems like you don't need the lookup tables.

Comment: @Doug The numbers are only used as an example above to show different choices, the real subjects have long titles

Comment: Ok, I think Jeeped's will work, but it would be helpful to show a couple of actual subjects and addons. If there's a pattern between them and the suffixes there might be a simpler solution.

Comment: @Doug Here's a small sample of the actual file - I know that the cases are different I'll need to tidy them up (will prob just use UPPER on them all) https://www.dropbox.com/s/v5f1gd5j3pwm0kl/ST.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: I don't know what the rest of the data looks like but `PROPER` may be a more aesthetically pleasing alternative to `UPPER`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula required is not at all off-putting if a cross-reference table of *Courses* and *Add-ons* is supplied.

[image]

The standard formula in E2 is,

```
 
=IF(AND(OR(C2=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, $G$2:$H$10, 2, FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, $G$2:$H$10, 2, FALSE), NA())), D2=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, $G$2:$H$10, 2, FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, $G$2:$H$10, 2, FALSE), NA()))), OR(C2=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, $G$2:$H$10, 2, FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, $G$2:$H$10, 2, FALSE), NA())), D2=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, $G$2:$H$10, 2, FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, $G$2:$H$10, 2, FALSE), NA())))), "Correct", "Error")
```

Fill down as necessary. The use of `IFERROR` (available since Excel 2007) makes doubling up functions like `VLOOKUP` a breeze. You can simply pass control over to a second version of the function if the first fails. Granted these still have to be doubled up to account for all possibilities, but there shouldn't be a large calculation load.

Do you need an extra condition to ensure that column C is not a duplicate of column D?

**EDIT:** Add check for duplicates

Checking for duplicates in both A:B and C:D shouldn't be an issue at all as they can be added into the existing `AND` function.. Here is a modification for both A:B and C:D.

```
 
=IF(AND(A2<>B2, C2<>D2, OR(C2=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, $G$2:$H$10, 2, FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, $G$2:$H$10, 2, FALSE), NA())), D2=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, $G$2:$H$10, 2, FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, $G$2:$H$10, 2, FALSE), NA()))), OR(C2=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, $G$2:$H$10, 2, FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, $G$2:$H$10, 2, FALSE), NA())), D2=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, $G$2:$H$10, 2, FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, $G$2:$H$10, 2, FALSE), NA())))), "Correct", "Error")
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped, that looks like it'll work fine. I'm not at home until later to try it. How much more work/complicated would it be to check that C and D aren't duplicates?